# Future with Coroutines co_await

Tags: c++, future, coroutine, c++20

Watching a c++ lecture (https://youtu.be/DLLt4anKXKU?t=1589), I tried to understand how future work with co_await; example:

```
auto compute = []() -> std::future<int> {
int fst = co_await std::async(get_first);
int snd = co_await std::async(get_second);
co_return fst + snd;
};
auto f = compute();
/* some heavy task */ 
f.get();
```

I can't understand how and when `co_await std::async(get_first)` returns control to `compute`. i.e how `std::future` implements an awaitable interface (type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is a full program that can await futures with C++20 coroutines. I did it myself these days to learn.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <coroutine>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::literals;



template <class T>
class FutureAwaitable {
public:
  template <class U> struct BasicPromiseType {
    auto get_return_object() {
      return FutureAwaitable<T>(CoroHandle::from_promise(*this));
    }

    std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept {
      std::cout << "Initial suspend\n";
      return {};
    }

    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept {
      std::cout << "Final suspend\n";
      return {};
    }

    template <class V>
    requires std::is_convertible_v<V, T>
    void return_value(V v) { _value = v; }

    void unhandled_exception() { throw; }

    std::optional<T> _value;
  };

  using promise_type = BasicPromiseType<FutureAwaitable<T>>;
  using CoroHandle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  explicit FutureAwaitable(CoroHandle h) : _parent(h) {  }

  ~FutureAwaitable() {
  }


  bool is_ready() const {
      auto & fut = std::get<FutureAwaitable<T> *>(&_parent);
      return fut->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) != std::future_status::ready;
  }

  FutureAwaitable(std::future<T> && f) {
      _f = &f;
  }

  T get() const { return promise()._value.value(); }

  std::future<T> & std_future() const {
    assert(_f->valid());
    return *_f;
  }

  bool await_ready() {
    if (!(_f->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready)) {
      std::cout << "Await ready IS ready\n";
      return true;
    }
    else
      std::cout << "Await ready NOT ready\n";
    return false;
  }

  auto await_resume() {
    std::cout << "Await resume" << std::endl;
    return std_future().get();
  }

  bool await_suspend(CoroHandle parent) {
      _parent = parent;
      std::cout << "Await suspend\n";
      return true;
  }

  void resume() {
    assert(_parent);
    _parent.resume();
  }

  auto parent() const { return _parent; }

  bool done() const noexcept {
    return _parent.done();
  }

private:
  auto & promise() const noexcept { return _parent.promise(); }

  CoroHandle _parent = nullptr;
  std::future<T> * _f = nullptr;

};

template <class T> auto operator co_await(std::future<T> &&f) {
  return FutureAwaitable<T>(std::forward<std::future<T>>(f));
}

template <class T> auto operator co_await(std::future<T> & f) {
  return FutureAwaitable<T>(std::forward<std::future<T>>(f));
}


FutureAwaitable<int> coroutine() {
  std::promise<int> p;
  auto fut = p.get_future();
  p.set_value(31);
  std::cout << "Entered func()" << std::endl;
  auto res = co_await std::move(fut);
  std::cout << "Continue func(): " << res << std::endl;

  auto computation = co_await std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
      int j = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
          j += i;
      }
      return j;
  });

  auto computation2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
      int j = 0;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(20s);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
          j += i;
      }
      return j;
  });

  auto computation3 = std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
      int j = 0;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(20s);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
          j += i;
      }
      return j;
  });
  co_await computation2;
  co_await computation3;

  std::cout << "Computation result is " << computation << std::endl;
  co_return computation;
}

#define ASYNC_MAIN(coro)                        \
    int main() {                                \
    FutureAwaitable<int> c = coro();                     \
    do { c.resume(); } while (!c.done());                \
    std::cout << "The coroutine returned " << c.get(); \
    return 0; \
}


ASYNC_MAIN(coroutine)
```

Comment: I do not see how this can work, because you never resume the suspended CoroHandle, and never subscribe to future completion, which should be done inside await_suspend(h) method.

Answer (score 3):

> how std::future implements an awaitable interface

Well as far as C++20 is concerned, it *doesn't*. C++20 provides `co_await` and its attendant language functionality, but it doesn't provide any actual awaitable types.

How `std::future` *could* implement the awaitable interface is basically the same as how `std::experimental::future` from the Concurrency TS implements [`future::then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then). `then` takes a function to be continued when the `future`'s value becomes available. The return value of `then` is a new `future<U>` (the old `future<T>` now becomes non-functional), where `U` is the new value that the given continuation function returns. That new `future` will only have a `U` available when the original value is available and when the continuation has processed it into the new value. In that order.

The exact details about how `.then` works depend entirely on how `future` is implemented. And it may depend on how the specific `future` was *created*, as `future`s from `std::async` have special properties that other `future`s don't.

`co_await` just makes this process much more digestible visually. A `co_await`able future would simply shove the coroutine handle into `future::then`, thereby altering the `future`.